# asp.net - Access public class in Masterpage from child page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I'm trying to access a public class in my MasterPage code file from a child page but cannot get it working. I've tried to use the same method as accessing a public int as follows but the child page doesn't recognise any of the class items.

**MasterPage.cs**

```cs
private int _Section;
public int  Section
{
    get{return _Section;}
    set{_Section = value;}
}

public class HeaderPanel
{
    private bool _Visible = true;
    public bool Visible
    {
        get { return _Visible; }
        set { _Visible = value; }
    }

    private string _Theme;
    public string Theme
    {
        get { return _Theme; }
        set { _Theme = value; }
    }

    public HeaderPanel(bool Visible, string Theme)
    {
        this.Visible = Visible;
        this.Theme = Theme;
    }
}
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Master.Section = 1; // This works
    Master.HeaderPanel.Visible = true; // This doesn't work
    Master.HeaderPanel.Theme = "Dark"; // This doesn't work       

}
```

The error message I get is:
'HeaderPanel': cannot reference a type through an expression

Comment: It looks like you're trying to access the properties on `HeaderPanel` as though their are `static`.  Did you forget to make them `static`?  Or forget to make an instance of the class in `MasterPage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Master.Section = 1;
```

This works because `Master` is a property on `Default` and that property is an instance of `MasterPage`.  You are simply setting the `Section` value on that instance.

```
Master.HeaderPanel.Visible = true;
```

This doesn't work because, while `Master` is still the same instance, `HeaderPanel` is a *type* and not an instance of anything.  So you're trying to set `Visible` *statically* on that type.

---

If you *meant* for it to be `static`, make it `static`:

```
private static bool _Visible = true;
public static bool Visible
{
    get { return _Visible; }
    set { _Visible = value; }
}
```

And access it via the type and not the instance:

```
MasterPage.HeaderPanel.Visible = true;
```

---

If, on the other hand (and possibly more likely?), you did *not* mean for it to be `static`, then you need an instance of the `HeaderPanel` type on a `MasterPage` instance.  So in `MasterPage` you'd create a property for that:

```
private HeaderPanel _header = new HeaderPanel();
public HeaderPanel Header
{
    get { return _header; }
    set { _header = value; }
}
```

Then you could access it through that property:

```
Master.Header.Visible = true;
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you. I knew there was something I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

```
private int _Section;
public int  Section
{
    get{return _Section;}
    set{_Section = value;}
}
//define your header panel as property 
public HeaderPanel Header {Get;Set;}
```

then you can use it as below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Master.Section = 1; // This works
    Master.Header.Visible = true; 
    Master.Header.Theme = "Dark";       
}
```